How to get intersection of strings in R tidy? Not union
I have two vectors of strings and I want to make an intersection and concatenate them into a new vector.
I found a complicated way to do it.
Is there a tidy function to use?
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
string_a <- c("ab", "bc", "cd", "df", "aq")
string_b <- c("ac", "bc", "bd", "df", "aq")

string_a <- string_a %>%  enframe() %>% dplyr::select(-name)

string_b <- string_b %>%  enframe() %>% dplyr::select(-name)
inter_str <- inner_join(string_a, string_b) %>%
  pull(value)



Why not use intersect()?

As I often quote, The DataMungerGuru says (roughly) "Don't tell me how you want to do something;  tell me what result you are trying to attain.

@Edward thanks, I have forgotten completely about intersect()

This is one of those occurences, where base has a straigthforward, easy-to-read, and perfect solution.
> string_a <- c("ab", "bc", "cd", "df", "aq")
> string_b <- c("ac", "bc", "bd", "df", "aq")
> base::intersect(string_a, string_b)
[1] "bc" "df" "aq"


To emphasize what Friede and Edward posted,
stra <- vector('character')
for(ja in 1:100) stra[ja] <- paste0(sample(letters,3),collapse='')
strb <- vector('character')
for(ja in 1:100) strb[ja] <- paste0(sample(letters,3),collapse='')

string_a <- c("ab", "bc", "cd", "df", "aq",stra)
string_b <- c("ac", "bc", "bd", "df", "aq",strb)

intb <- function(string_a,string_b)  base::intersect(string_a, string_b)


intt <- function(string_a,string_b) {

string_a <- string_a %>%  enframe() %>% dplyr::select(-name)

string_b <- string_b %>%  enframe() %>% dplyr::select(-name)
inter_str <- inner_join(string_a, string_b) %>%
  pull(value)
  }

Unit: microseconds
                     expr       min         lq        mean     median        uq        max
 intb(string_a, string_b)    13.268    15.7715    22.70744    20.6175    28.895     41.705
 intt(string_a, string_b) 13454.018 13686.7150 19217.40940 13834.7585 14644.317 453467.971
 neval
   100
   100


This is my awkward and complex solution into something that base R can solve easily.
string_a <- string_a %>%  enframe() %>% dplyr::select(-name)

string_b <- string_b %>%  enframe() %>% dplyr::select(-name)
inter_str <- inner_join(string_a, string_b) %>%
  pull(value)

